# Node.js Sequelize: Error in migration with foreign key

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, migration

I have an existing SQL Server database where I have to create a new table.

Existing **Image** table has column as shown in image:

[image]

I'm creating a new table using migration with a column referencing to this Image table.

My Query is

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('NewTable', {
      IdNewTable: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      IdImage: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'Image',
          key: 'IdImage',
        },
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('NewTable');
  }
};
```

While running a migration, I'm getting this error

> ERROR: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong datatype

It should be

```
type: 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER',
defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
primaryKey: true,
allowNull: false,
```